# Idiomatic way to aggregate map results into a Map datastructure

Tags: scala

I feel this should be simple but can't think of an idiomatic way to write this

```
case class Dataset(name: String)

val datasets = List(Dataset("first"), Dataset("second"))

def getData(datasetName: String): InputStream = { 
  // not important 
}

val data: Map[String, InputStream] = {
  // aggregate this so the dataset name maps to the result of getData
  datasets.foreach(dataset => getData(dataset.name))
  ...
}
```

what I have currently creates a mutable map and puts the data one-by-one, then makes it immutable which is terrible imo

```
val data: Map[String, InputStream] = {
  val map = new util.HashMap[String, InputStream]()
  datasets.foreach(dataset => map.put(dataset.name, getData(dataset.name))
  map.asScala.toMap
}
```

Comment: What about `datasets.map(dataset => dataset.name -> getData(dataset.name)).toMap`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yeah that's exactly what I was looking for. Ugh thank you